# Symfony Optional Phone Entry validation Integrity Error: Column 'phone' cannot be null

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have the following Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=25,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=25,
     *     minMessage="The surname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The surname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number")
     * @AssertPhoneNumber
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=255,
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $organization;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=255,
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $occupation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
      $this->name=$name;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function setSurname(string $surname)
    {
      $this->surname=$surname;

      return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setPhone($phoneNum)
    {
      $this->phone=$phoneNum;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
      return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setOrganization($organization)
    {
      $this->organization=$organization;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getOrganization()
    {
      return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOccupation($occupation)
    {
      $this->occupation=$occupation;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getOccupation()
    {
      return $this->occupation;
    }
}
```

That as you can see has a field named `$phone`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number")
 * @AssertPhoneNumber
 */
protected $phone;
```

In my logic this field should be optional  and not required for registration, so in order to do that I extended the FosUserBundle form accorditly:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Form\Type\PhoneNumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;


class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.name","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('surname',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.surname","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('phone',PhoneNumberType::class,["label"=>"register.phonenum",'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('organization',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.organization","required"=>false,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('occupation',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.position","required"=>false,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle']);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

As you can see I set it as NotRequired as you can see in following snippet:

```
->add('phone',PhoneNumberType::class,["label"=>"register.phonenum",'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
```

But when I try to test the registration I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'phone' cannot be null

I also in order to avoid this type of error I changed the definition into:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number")
 */
protected $phone;
```

But I still get the error. Is somehow a way to set a field as null?

Also for validation I use the `giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php` coposer package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missing parameter in the Doctrine Annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number", nullable=true)
 * @AssertPhoneNumber
 */
protected $phone;
```

And don't forget to run `d:s:u --dump-sql|--force` or to generate your migrations ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="phone_number", nullable=true)
* @AssertPhoneNumber
*/
protected $phone;
```

I believe this would work.